# simple UIButton always crashes my app on touch

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibutton

i have a strange problem.
On my view i have two segmented controls and one button.
The segmented controls work perfectly but my button crashes the app when i touch it.
NSLog won't be called anymore.

```
PageViewController.h

paintingOptions = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,30,100,100)];
[paintingOptions setTitle:@"Ok" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[paintingOptions setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[paintingOptions addTarget:self action:@selector(showPaintingOptions:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:paintingOptions];

-(void) showPaintingOptions: (id) sender {
   NSLog(@"Button pressed");
}
```

Any hints on how to solve that ?

Debug:

The debug output says nothing but (gdb). 
Xcode shows me this line:

```
PDFViewController.h

- (UIView *)view {
    return self.scrollView; }

0x32c37102  <+0014>  ldr    r1, [pc, #16]   (0x32c37114 <-[UIViewController nextResponder]+32>)
```

But this function is in another view controller.
So the view where i have the button in is a subview of this scrollView.

Adding PageViewController to PDFViewController:

```
- (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page
{
if (page < 0)
    return;
if (page >= kNumberOfPages)
    return;

// replace the placeholder if necessary
PageViewController *controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:page];
if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null])
{
    //page+1 cause CGPDF indexing starts with 1
    controller = [[PageViewController alloc] initWithPageNumberAndUrl:page+1: [chapter urlOnFilesystem]];
    [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
    [controller release];
}

// add the controller's view to the scroll view
if (controller.view.superview == nil)
{
    CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    controller.view.frame = frame;

    [scrollView addSubview:controller.view];


}
}
```

Comment: can u tell me what the exception while crashing?

Comment: You have it marked as `IBAction`, have you set any event-handling in a NIB-file?

Comment: Sorry, the IBAction was from before when i tested with a nib.

Comment: Is the method `showPaintingOptions:(id)sender` declared in your .h file?

Comment: Yes, it is declared. @Deepak Debug added

Comment: Is the first piece of code part of a different view controller? If so, which controller calls which one?

Comment: @Deepak PDFViewController calls PageViewController.

Comment: Can you paste the code where the PDFViewController creates and calls PageViewController?

Comment: This code looks clean. Are you releasing the `PageViewController` objects anywhere? It looks like it were the case. Are you sure there is no more console log data available. Do `Cmd+7` in Xcode and copy-paste the topmost `Debug ***` logs you see.

Comment: No, thats all the debug. It's really strange because the function calls of the segmented control are working and that is nearly the same as a button i think..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the crash log it looks like **-(void) showPaintingOptions: (id) sender** is not in your target self. Please make sure that.